# Import a .MDB file into SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005, ms-access

Hey I have a .MDB file which contains a database for an old site which I have to upgrade to SQL Server 2005. I'm very familiar with SQL Server 2005 but know very little about Access and .MDB files.

Can someone demonstrate the steps in which I can Import a .MDB database into SQL Server 2005. With preferably doing it from SQL Server Management Studio.

Thanks in advance

Comment: See: [How to convert an Access database](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/237980)

Comment: The SQL Server Migration Assistant for Access is much more versatile than the Access upsizing wizard. The cited Knowledge Base article is also quite out of date (A2000 is the latest version mentioned in it).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are lots of ways to do this - manually or with the help of some wizards.

Check out [Microsoft SQL Server 2005 - Migration for Microsoft Access](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2005/en/us/migration-access.aspx) for guidance and grab the SQL Server Migration Assistant for Access (SSMA for Access) to upgrade easily.

Comment: The SSMA is much more versatile than the Access upsizing wizard. Also, it doesn't have the version incompatibilities that the upsizing wizard has (e.g., to upsize to SQL 2005, you need A2007 or later).

Answer (score 0):

You could define a new DSN which connects to your SQL2005 server, then create the same DB structure in SQL2005.

Load your MDB into access. Connect to your new DSN within Access, then you can simply copy/paste rows between the 2 databases.

Comment: Why bother with that? With a DSN you can use the Access EXPORT command on the FILE menu and it will create the tables and insert the data for you. You might have issues with data types not necessarily being exactly what you want, but that could be tweaked after the data tables are created by the export process. Once the tables exist, you surely wouldn't use copy and paste, but use SQL INSERTs to copy data.